# best practice to implement in-application mailing/inbox system

Tags: email, architecture

I need to implement an in-application message-box system (like any forum/social network has).
Number of users is in the tens of thousands and up.
I am thinking to do it using an actual email server and write a client for it inside the application (or just pick an open source client and adjust it to appear like a private messages system).
Or
Should I just do it as an integral part of my application (DB, server side and all)?

Which approach is the correct one?
(I do not think this is a consideration, but the bulk of the application is written in PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Use your application back-end.

Email (SMTP/IMAP) sounds simple but has way too much administration and programming overhead if you do it properly - or you get random problems.

If you need to send emails to your users (which you shouldn't need to - I quite like how Stackoverflow works for example in that respect) then just be a client to email (SMTP).

Another issue with 'email' is it's an old protocol which does not fit into todays needs. Hence we have new protocols and applications, like [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) and [Google Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wave).